# Flutter, fetching specfic image from website

Tags: html, http, flutter

I'm learning flutter and want to fetch various images which are the thumbnail of the cartoon. I used `HTTP` library and fetched response data.

But, how can I extract that image?

Website: https://comic.naver.com/webtoon/weekdayList.nhn?week=

[image]

```
Future<http.Response> _getData() async {
    return await http.get('https://comic.naver.com/webtoon/weekdayList.nhn?week=');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Fetching"),
          onPressed: (){
            _getData().then((response){
              //dom.Document document = parser.parse(response.body);
              print(response.body);
            }).catchError((e) => print(e));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

---

> What I want to do is below.
>
> 1. Fetching web page as HTML code
> 2. Find image url of each cartoon
> 3. Fetch that image

Comment: Why are you not using https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/NetworkImage-class.html ?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Maybe because he is new to this and doesn't know about it?

Comment: To use that library, I have to know the url of image and it leads to that have to extract that url in web page.

Comment: So you want to extract the URL, not the image.

Comment: Yes, I edited plz see

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you have a basic example, after you press the top-right button, you will get the images in a `ListView`:

```
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'package:html/parser.dart' as parser;
    import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;


   ...create your StatefulWidget



     class ParsingWidgetState extends State<ParsingWidget> {
      List<String> list = List();

      void _getData() async {
        final response =
            await http.get('https://comic.naver.com/webtoon/weekdayList.nhn?week=');
        dom.Document document = parser.parse(response.body);
        final elements = document.getElementsByClassName('thumb');

        setState(() {
          list = elements
              .map((element) =>
                  element.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].attributes['src'])
              .toList();
        });
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              actions: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _getData();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            body: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: list.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Image.network(
                  list[index],
                  height: 200.0,
                );
              },
            ));
      }
    }
```

Try using FutureBuilder instead `setState`, this is just a working sample.

More info:

- https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html
- https://flutter-academy.com/async-in-flutter-futurebuilder/