# How to read an image from a non-image link in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to read images from network. However, what I want is a bit different than normal. Normally, everyone can use [`Image.network`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.network.html) to read images from image links. However, what I want is to read images from non-image links, such as [this link](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2022-11-15/russia-expected-to-agree-to-extend-black-sea-grain-export-deal).

I tried using [`Image.network`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.network.html) to do this without success.

I didn't include the code because I don't think the code has anything to do with this.

If you need more info feel free to leave a comment!

How to read an image from a non-image link in Flutter? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I didn't get what you want exactly, you want an image inside the web page?

Comment: In other words you want to read images from HTML pages?

Comment: @eamirho3ein yes you are right

Comment: Does it answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62092032/how-do-you-scrape-an-image-from-a-website-using-flutter

Comment: @RohanThacker I don't understand what "HTML pages" means

Comment: @MyCar HTML is a structured language used to create pages.

Comment: I don't think that would be possible.

Comment: @RohanThacker I know, so you say "HTML pages", do you mean "pages"?

Comment: @SiddharthMehra I'm trying the code from that answer

Comment: @SiddharthMehra I get two errors: 
`The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.`, `A value of type 'Null' can't be returned from the method 'getProfileImageUrl' because it has a return type of 'Future<String>'.`

Comment: @eamirho3ein that's okay. However, thank you for taking the time to reply to me

Comment: check `html` parser package: https://pub.dev/packages/html

Comment: @pskink I don't understand what you are talking about. Can you share more details?

Comment: @pskink I see you edited your answer. But I have a question, how to use this package, can you answer this question and share the code?

Comment: you have to `parse()` your html and find the URL of the image you want to show

Comment: @pskink how do I find the URL of the image?

Comment: `final dom = html.parse('<p>foo <img href="test1.jpg" alt="img1"/>  <b>bar</b> <img href="test2.jpg"/> </p>');
for (final img in dom.querySelectorAll('img')) {
print(img.attributes);
}` - i dont know if param passed to `querySelectorAll` is ok but it works

Answer (score 0):

Potentially a repost for : [Flutter, fetching specfic image from website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984429/flutter-fetching-specfic-image-from-website)

In this case you just need to extract all the elements having the word **thumb** in them which can be done by the method as described in the link above :

```
void _getData() async {
        final response =
            await http.get('https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2022-11-15/russia-expected-to-agree-to-extend-black-sea-grain-export-deal');
        dom.Document document = parser.parse(response.body);
        final elements = document.getElementsByClassName('thumb');

        setState(() {
          list = elements
              .map((element) =>
                  element.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].attributes['src'])
              .toList();
        });
      }
```

What this is doing is just creating a list of all the images available in the source code of the particular URL that you're entering.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I get error: `The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.`

Comment: Yeah my bad just use `final response = await http.get(
        Uri.https('https://comic.naver.com/webtoon/weekdayList.nhn?week='));`

Comment: I get error: `I/flutter ( 4402): FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)
I/flutter ( 4402): //comic.naver.com/webtoon/weekdayList.nhn?week=
I/flutter ( 4402): ^`

Comment: Changing `Uri.https` to `Uri.parse` solves that issue try it...

Comment: It works! However, it returns [this link](https://shared-comic.pstatic.net/thumb/webtoon/797582/thumbnail/thumbnail_IMAG04_cd527a6f-5197-4ba3-a20e-1aa45400e581.jpg) and the image is really weird…

Comment: haha that's why I edited the original link with yours in the answer